# Is bad idea to utilize helper functions on integration tests?

Tags: unit-testing, integration-tests, phpunit

In my job I have a small disagreement on whether we should utilize helper functions for making datasets especially in `laravel` framework. A sample for the test is:

```
namespace Tests\MyAppTests;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class MyTest extends TestCase
{
  private function makeATwoHourSpan(Carbon $now, &$start, &$end)
  {
     $start = new Carbon($now);
     $start->modify("-1 hour");

     $end = new Carbon($now);
     $end->modify("+1 hour");
  }

  public function testSomething()
  {
     $now=Carbon::now();
     $start=null;
     $end=null;

     this->makeATwoHourSpan($now, $start, $end);
     //Rest Of Test Here
  }


  public function testSomethingElse()
  {
     $now=Carbon::now();
     $start=null;
     $end=null;

     this->makeATwoHourSpan($now, $start, $end);
     //Rest Of Test Here
  }
}
```

The argument that my supervisor says is that using the `makeATwoHourSpan` method even though makes the code DRY it does not aid the readability of the test. Also he mentioned that a test should be autonomous and a easy to run as standalone without any helper function except the tools provided from the framework.

So my question is: Should I avoid utilizing "helper" functions especially when I make test data when I make tests, or having a function for data creation makes is the way to go?

Comment: We're not here to solve your arguments with your supervisor for you.  Software is software, including unit tests; precepts like DRY should apply everywhere.  That said, your supervisor has a point; unit tests should be as "shallow" and as self-contained as possible.  The only kind of helper methods I would entertain are those that have directly to do with the testing process, like `Assert()`.  Business domain-specific helper methods like `makeATwoHourSpan` can be useful, but they don't really have a place in testing harnesses.

Comment: Why this `makeATwoHourSpan` method is "special"? I did not understand what you mean by "helper" function here. It's very common to create a base scenario before running a specific integration test. Otherwise, each integration test will have very long setups, with a lot of duplication among the tests and hard to maintain.

Comment: This method helps me because I need to ganarate a specific datetime between a specirfic range hence the first way to do that is to create a daterange from a given time.

Answer (score 1):

I think your supervisor is off track, and I think creating helper functions for integration tests is a perfect way to use OO and DRY principles in your test case design. I've made a career of developing integration tests and integration test frameworks, and do this same sort of thing and much more at every job I do. To *not* extract the duplicate code out of the tests into a shared function would make your tests harder (more expensive) to maintain. What good manager wants to *decrease* maintainability of source code, rather than increase it?

I might even go a step farther and move `makeATwoHourSpan` into a separate class, since odds are good that you will want other utility functions for creating and manipulating dates in your tests.